# Access Variable Dynamically

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring, naming-conventions, dynamic-variables

I have many buttons named like this:

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *Round1Num1;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *Round1Num2;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *Round1Num3;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *Round1Num4;

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *Round2Num1;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *Round2Num2;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *Round2Num3;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *Round2Num4;
```

and so on.

I was wondering if I could access them dynamically using `stringWithFormat` or a similar method.

Example (Sorry if the code is wrong!):

Instead of `self.Round1Num1` I could call `self.[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Round%dNum%d", 1, 1]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `-performSelector:`:

```
NSString *round2Num1ButtonAccessorSelectorStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Round%dNum%d", 2, 1];
SEL selector = NSSelectorFromString(round2Num1ButtonAccessorSelectorStr);
if ([self respondsToSelector:selector])
    UIButton *round2Num1Button = [self performSelector:selector];
```

For context, `[self performSelector:@selector(someSelector)]` is essentially the equivalent to `self.someSelector` (in the case of a property accessor) which resolves to `[self someSelector]`. All cases actually call the same runtime function, `objc_msgSend(self, someSelector)`.

Specifically in this context, we're creating a local variable that points to the same reference concealed by the respective IBOutlet property on the VC instance. If the property doesn't exist, then neither will the selector (most likely) so you need to safeguard from an unrecognized selector exception via `-respondsToSelector:`.

Comment: So in this example, calling round2Num1Button.tag would be the same as calling self.Round2Num1.tag, correct?

Comment: I also receive this error: Implicit conversion of an Objective-C pointer to 'SEL' is disallowed with ARC. I think you meant to use NSSelectorFromString instead of NSStringFromSelector

Comment: Whoops, dislexic on my part. Should be `NSSelectorFromString`. Also, to answer your first question, yes -- they point to the same object reference.